# Ansible append remote directory to local with synchronize

Tags: ansible

I am experiencing an issue when using `with_items` loop to try and sync multiple remote dirs and files to local. From what I can see it just selects the last dir from the remote in the structure and overwrites the file there, I've explicitly stated to include the whole path. I've tried the recursive flag but that didn't worked for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
---
- name: sync dirs and files
  hosts: hosts_group1
  become: yes
  user: username1

  tasks:
  - name: Fetch stuff from the remote and save to local
    ansible.posix.synchronize:
      src: "{{ item.source }}"
      dest: ~/dir1_local/dir2_local/dir3_local/{{ inventory_hostname }}/
      rsync_opts: [
      --include=*/,
      --include=*.conf,
      --exclude=*
      ]
      mode: pull
      rsync_path: sudo -u username1 rsync
    delegate_to: localhost
    become: yes
    become_username: username1
    with_items:
      - { source: '/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote' }
      - { source: '/rootdir2_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote' }
      - { source: '/rootdir3_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote' }
```

and this is what I get:

```
changed: [inventoryhost10 -> localhost] => (item=/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --dirs --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u username1 rsync' --include=*/ --include=*.conf --exclude=* --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' username1@inventoryhost10:/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote /home/username1/dir1_local/dir2_local/dir3_local/inventoryhost10",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_local_rsync_password": null,
            "_local_rsync_path": "rsync",
            "_substitute_controller": false,
            "archive": true,
            "checksum": false,
            "compress": true,
            "copy_links": false,
            "delay_updates": true,
            "delete": false,
            "dest": "/home/username1/dir1_local/dir2_local/dir3_local/inventoryhost10",
            "dest_port": null,
            "dirs": true,
            "existing_only": false,
            "group": null,
            "link_dest": null,
            "links": null,
            "mode": "pull",
            "owner": null,
            "partial": false,
            "perms": null,
            "private_key": null,
            "recursive": null,
            "rsync_opts": [
                "--include=*/",
                "--include=*.conf",
                "--exclude=*"
            ],
            "rsync_path": "sudo -u dagger rsync",
            "rsync_timeout": 0,
            "set_remote_user": true,
            "src": "username1@inventoryhost10:/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote",
            "ssh_args": null,
            "ssh_connection_multiplexing": false,
            "times": null,
            "verify_host": false
        }
    },
    "item": "/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote",
    "msg": ".d..t...... dir4_remote/\n>f..t...... dir4_remote/test1.conf\n>f..t...... dir4_remote/test2.conf\n>f..t...... dir4_remote/test5.conf\n",
    "rc": 0,
    "stdout_lines": [
        ".d..t...... dir4_remote/",
        ">f..t...... dir4_remote/test1.conf",
        ">f..t...... dir4_remote/test2.conf",
        ">f..t...... dir4_remote/test5.conf"
    ]
}
```

I am using the same `username1` on both ends for simplicity. So from what you can see above it just syncs the last dir in the chain `dir4_remote` which is not really what I expected and it dumps all the files there from rootdir_remote, rootdir2_remote and rootdir3_remote (all dirs have the same filenames hence I want them separated)

My expectation was that I would see something like this:

```
inventoryhost10/
├── rootdir2_remote
│   └── dir2_remote
│       └── dir3_remote
│           └── dir4_remote
│               ├── test1.conf
│               ├── test2.conf
│               └── test5.conf
├── rootdir3_remote
│   └── dir2_remote
│       └── dir3_remote
│           └── dir4_remote
│               ├── test1.conf
│               ├── test2.conf
│               └── test5.conf
└── rootdir_remote
    └── dir2_remote
        └── dir3_remote
            └── dir4_remote
                ├── test1.conf
                ├── test2.conf
                └── test5.conf

12 directories, 9 files
```

Apologies for the long post, just wanted to be as clear as possible. If anyone has any suggestion please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: `dest: ~/dir1_local/dir2_local/dir3_local/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ item.source }}`, rather, I would say.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, didn't crossed my mind thanks. However that just brings another set of issues as `dest` won't create the dirs it just targets them where to save the files if I am right? since it throws this:

`    "msg": "Warning: Permanently added 'inventoryhost10 ,10.0.0.5' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nrsync: [Receiver] mkdir \"~/dir1_local/dir2_local/dir3_local/inventoryhost10/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote\" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(787) [Receiver=3.2.3]\n",`

Comment: Well, possibly, but if you target the folder `/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote` right away, then you are saying something like `cp /rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote /some/other/folder`. That won't mimic the folder structure to `/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote`, otherwise that means you could never move or synchornize something without bringing its actual folder hierarchy.

Comment: Hmmm so concatenating something that doesn't exist on my controller(localhost/username1) in `dest: ~/dir1_local/dir2_local/dir3_local/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ item.source }}` won't create it is what you're trying to say right?

Comment: No, what I am saying is that you won't have synchronise to create folder as long as you are doing it at that level. You would be able to achieve it the synchronising from the ancestor where you want to folder to be created though. And if that's not possible, use a `file` task to create those folder beforehand.

Comment: Ah.... I was thinking on using `file` and actually I did ended up doing it like that, but I wonder if that's the only way as it's bit hard coded :(. However I got what I wanted so I will mark this as resolved. Posting the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

After all it turned out that I had to "hardcode" the creation of the directory structure, so whoever will use this make sure that you change that bit. Here it is:

```
---
- name: Sync directories and files from remote
  hosts: hosts_group1
  become: yes
  become_user: username1
  tasks:
  - name: Create the local dirs
    file:
      path: ~/dir1_local/dir2_local/dir3_local/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ item.source }}
      state: directory
    with_items:
      - { source: '/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote' }
      - { source: '/rootdir2_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote' }
      - { source: '/rootdir3_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote' }
    delegate_to: localhost

- hosts: hosts_group1
  tasks:
  - name: Fetch files from the remote and save to local
    ansible.posix.synchronize:
      src: "{{ item.source }}"
      dest: ~/dir1_local/dir2_local/dir3_local/{{ inventory_hostname }}{{ item.source }}
      rsync_opts: [
      --include=*/,
      --include=*.conf,
      --exclude=*
      ]
      mode: pull
      rsync_path: sudo -u username1 rsync
    delegate_to: localhost
    become: yes
    become_user: username1
    with_items:
      - { source: '/rootdir_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote/' }
      - { source: '/rootdir2_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote/' }
      - { source: '/rootdir3_remote/dir2_remote/dir3_remote/dir4_remote/' }
```